# Linking boost library in node native module, object file requiring alternative library version

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I recently had the need to pull in the Boost Graph Library for one of the native node modules that I work on, along with boost serialization. There is a separate VS project that I do all of my development and testing for this module. The project compiles, links, and works as expected when run from the VS project.

I am having issues when I try to link the static serialization library with my module when building with node-gyp. I have included the full path to the serialization library in the libraries section of the binding.gyp file. In the object file produced from the node-gyp compiled file, the following line is causing a linker failure:

> /FAILIFMISMATCH:"_CRT_STDIO_ISO_WIDE_SPECIFIERS=0"^@^Dlibboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_67.lib^@^Dlibboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_67.lib^@^Duuid.lib^@^Duuid.lib^@

The object file is expecting libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_67.lib. When the build process tries to link the file, the linker spits out an error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_67.lib'

However, boost built libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_67.lib which is a different version than what the object file is expecting. I have tried to build the version that the object file is looking for, but I cannot seem to get boost to do so (each time I try, it skips all of the targets, even though I am specifying an alternative toolset).

How can I change the library version that the object file is expecting?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to build the "right" version of the serialization library, I had been using `toolset=msvc-140`. It should have been `toolset=msvc-14.0`. Sometimes I am dumb.